# No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar'

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I try to change my HelloWorld Application holo theme to Material.Light.DarkActionBar theme(As said by What's new Android Development tools session). But I got following error. I try to change target SDK version is 21. But We didn't have 21 SDK in SDK Manager. In that session,they said,set style xml for v-21.

**values/styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

**values-v21/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    !-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ramapps.helloworld"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

**Error:**

```
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platforms/android-20/android.jar -M /Users/Ram_PC/Ram/MyDrive/My_Workspaces/Android_Studio_Workspace_L/HelloWorld/app/build/intermediates/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/Ram_PC/Ram/MyDrive/My_Workspaces/Android_Studio_Workspace_L/HelloWorld/app/build/intermediates/res/debug -A /Users/Ram_PC/Ram/MyDrive/My_Workspaces/Android_Studio_Workspace_L/HelloWorld/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug -m -J /Users/Ram_PC/Ram/MyDrive/My_Workspaces/Android_Studio_Workspace_L/HelloWorld/app/build/generated/source/r/debug -F /Users/Ram_PC/Ram/MyDrive/My_Workspaces/Android_Studio_Workspace_L/HelloWorld/app/build/intermediates/libs/app-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.ramapps.helloworld -0 apk
  Error Code:
    1
  Output:
    /Users/Ram_PC/Ram/MyDrive/My_Workspaces/Android_Studio_Workspace_L/HelloWorld/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/values-v21/values.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

Comment: *But We didn't have 21 SDK in SDK Manager* What does that tell you? Also you should probably change your manifest XML for the API versions.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar In SDK Manager they mentioned like Android L(API 20,L preview).Also I tried to set minSDK version in manifest xml.But not works

Comment: AFAIK API20 is more or less for wearables (as you can see in your error it uses android-4.4W). Changing _compileSdkVersion_ to _'android-L'_ could help.

Comment: @harism I have the same issue and I am attempting with buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try to set the values in the `build.gradle` like this (updated for API 25):

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21 //oldest version you would like to support
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Not tested it, but I can change to `minSdkVersion 16` and it still works fine.

Comment: Any idea how we'd do this using phonegap build? using `<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
        <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light"/>
    </gap:config-file>` it returns the same error, but it works with `Theme.Holo.Light`

Comment: I suggest fixing the odd number of brackets in the code snippet. Thx!

Answer (score 8):

We can not install apps that target L Preview on anything but L devices.

Changing `res/values/styles.xml`, `Theme.Material.Light` to `Theme.Light` and following `build.gradle` worked for me.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.android.market.licensing'
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
```

Although `Theme.Material.Light` is part of the 20sdk version but somehow it is not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Set Target of Your Application to API Level 21 from AssemblyMenifest.xml or add `<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="21" android:minSdkVersion="19" />` tag to your AssemblyMenifest.xml

Answer (score 2):

I changed **Theme.Material.Light** to **Theme.Light** and it worked for me.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me too, and don't forget to do:
    "tns prepare android"    followed by:    "tns prepare android"

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you need to set your `buildToolsVersion` to pre Android L version.

Here my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mayuonline.ribbit"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.+'
}
```

Also make sure to change the `styles.xml` as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

This should resolve the problem.