# Jenkins Gradle Build Issue(Execution failed for task ':app:processPackagingOptionsDebugResources'.)

Tags: android, jenkins, aapt, gradle-plugin

I am trying to build Android App through Jenkins, using Gradle Plugin. When I buld the application, I am getting the following exception pasted below. This application is runnning well using Android Studio, but unable to build using Jenkins. Please let me know, what could be the issue.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\AndroidApp\app\src\main\res\values-v21\styles.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\AndroidApp\app\src\main\res\values-v21\styles.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\AndroidApp\app\src\main\res\values-v21\styles.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\AndroidApp\app\src\main\res\values-v21\styles.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\AndroidApp\app\src\main\res\values-v21\styles.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\AndroidApp\app\src\main\res\values-v21\styles.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\AndroidApp\app\src\main\res\values-v21\styles.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode'.

FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processPackagingOptionsDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\AndroidStudioSDK\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Please find the build.gradle below:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
```

}

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

class BooleanExtension {
    boolean value

    BooleanExtension(boolean value) {
        this.value = value
    }

    public void setValue(boolean value) {
        this.value = value
    }

    public boolean getValue() {
        return value
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
//    def voiceSearch = false;


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.packageid'
        versionName "1.0.0"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 10000

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            renderscriptOptimLevel 3
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }



    }




dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

I also removed style from value-v21 then I get the following Exception

```
Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml:2 : Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml:2 : Unexpected end tag string
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values-hdpi\values-hdpi.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle.Common'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\design\23.1.0\res\values-sw600dp\values-sw600dp.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\design\23.1.0\res\values-land\values-land.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values-large\values-large.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values-large\values-large.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.FixedSize'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values-v11\values-v11.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values-v11\values-v11.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values-v12\values-v12.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values-v12\values-v12.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.EditText'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.DialogWindowTitle.AppCompat'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529534/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-androidtheme-material-light-dark)

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing to note is that `(Execution failed for task ':app:processPackagingOptionsDebugResources'.)` **is not the error**. That is the **Gradle error**, caused by an error in your app. That "error in your app" is the actual error.

Above that Gradle error, you can see multiple app errors (here are 2 examples):

```
styles.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
styles.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle'.
```

These are your actual errors. Now about these. You can see it says:

```
No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle'.
```

Usually this is caused by a problem in your `build.gradle` file. At the `android {...}` part, make sure you have the compile sdk and build tools version set to the newest versions. Because you use "values-21", you should use v21 for compiling too:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"
}
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Yes , I am using the latest version
 compileSdkVersion 23
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

Comment: Then this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light

Comment: Any more suggesstions, I have updated the issue in more details.

Comment: The same Gradle works well in Android Studio, but not working with Jenkins? Any Suggestions.

Comment: @Safy Try using "@android:style/Widget.AppCompat" instead