# Gradle build keeps failing. File not found error comes in cache

Tags: java, android, caching

A couple of weeks ago I was programming an app. It was working and running successfully then. Today I tried opening Android Studio and I keep on getting the following error in the gradle build:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Yasmeen\Desktop\Tarikh Uni\OrganiserApp\Organiser\.gradle\2.8\taskArtifacts\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
> C:\Users\Yasmeen\Desktop\Tarikh Uni\OrganiserApp\Organiser\.gradle\2.8\taskArtifacts\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.88 secs
```

I don't know what to do. I've googled it and have attempted some of the answers like deleting the scripts folder in the .gradle folder then restart Android studio but that doesn't help.

EDIT = I tried copying the 'cache.properties' file from the ...2.8/cache folder into my project. It does go further into the gradle build but now these errors comes up. Shows up in the gradle console build:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027windowActionBar\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Yasmeen\\Desktop\\Tarikh Uni\\OrganiserApp\\Organiser\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles.xml","position":{"startLine":10,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":384,"endLine":13,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":532}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027windowNoTitle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Yasmeen\\Desktop\\Tarikh Uni\\OrganiserApp\\Organiser\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles.xml","position":{"startLine":10,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":384,"endLine":13,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":532}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027windowActionBar\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Yasmeen\\Desktop\\Tarikh Uni\\OrganiserApp\\Organiser\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values-v21\\styles.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":20,"endLine":7,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":321}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027windowNoTitle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Yasmeen\\Desktop\\Tarikh Uni\\OrganiserApp\\Organiser\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values-v21\\styles.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":20,"endLine":7,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":321}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Yasmeen\\Desktop\\Tarikh Uni\\OrganiserApp\\Organiser\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":19}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027colorAccent\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Yasmeen\\Desktop\\Tarikh Uni\\OrganiserApp\\Organiser\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles.xml","position":{"startLine":3,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":57,"endLine":8,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":376}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027colorPrimary\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Yasmeen\\Desktop\\Tarikh Uni\\OrganiserApp\\Organiser\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles.xml","position":{"startLine":3,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":57,"endLine":8,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":376}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027colorPrimaryDark\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Yasmeen\\Desktop\\Tarikh Uni\\OrganiserApp\\Organiser\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles.xml","position":{"startLine":3,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":57,"endLine":8,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":376}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Yasmeen\\Desktop\\Tarikh Uni\\OrganiserApp\\Organiser\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":25}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Yasmeen\\Desktop\\Tarikh Uni\\OrganiserApp\\Organiser\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":30}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Yasmeen\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.22 secs
```

From the gradles messages build:

```
    Error:(3, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
C:\Users\Yasmeen\Desktop\Tarikh Uni\OrganiserApp\Organiser\app\src\main\res\values-v21\styles.xml
C:\Users\Yasmeen\Desktop\Tarikh Uni\OrganiserApp\Organiser\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml
Error:(3, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
Error:(11, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
Error:(11, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
Error:(4, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
Error:(4, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.
Error:(20) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
Error:(4, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.
C:\Users\Yasmeen\Desktop\Tarikh Uni\OrganiserApp\Organiser\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
Error:(26) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar'.
Error:(31) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Yasmeen\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: find any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try without space in he path. `\Tarikh Uni\`

Comment: But thats the folders name. How do I fix the space? Would I just rename it?

Comment: Move your project to a different location, so there are no spaces in any folders leading to it. Not guaranteed to work, but often is the problem. Just had this yesterday with Android Studio and Gradle

Comment: I created a new project, copied the manifest file, layouts and the activities files to the new project. I was hoping that would work but it doesn't work. The gradle build keeps on giving errors on this part:  `:app:processDebugResources`

Comment: I wounder about `\u0027windowActionBar\u0027` do you have some additional `'` somewhere where they do not belong? `\u0027` =  `' `

Comment: Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529534/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-androidtheme-material-light-dark & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812302/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name

Answer (score 0):

I have counted the same problem, because my application module dependence another library,  they all dependence a common library. The build.gradle of common library include

```
dataBinding { enabled = true }
```

but my application module did not include

```
dataBinding { enabled = true }
```

in the android closure .
then I add

```
dataBinding { enabled = true }
```

in my application module android closure. then my project can run normally.
Hope this can help you.